# Add progress bar in navigation bar

Tags: iphone, navigation, progress-bar

I am developing an iPhone app and want to show a file upload progress bar in the top navigation bar like the iPhone SMS message sending status bar. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Pretty easy, just get a reference to the UIView that you want to put in the bar, and call `addSubview`:

```
UIView progressBar = ...;
[navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:progressBar];
progressBar.frame = CGRectMake( ... ); // Position it
```

Answer (score 2):

Better would be create a progress bar and place it here.

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = progressBar;
```